# Is there a way to synchronise visdom updates?

Tags: python, deep-learning, visdom

I'm working on a deep learning model which takes image inputs, encodes them into a latent representation and reconstructs them.

I'm using visdom to visualise the inputs, outputs, latent variables, and monitor the loss function. I create a `vis = visdom.Visdom()` object and pass it into the network. As the network uses the various latent variables, the Visdom object visualises them with `vis.image(...)`.

The problem is this design means the images get drawn in an unsynchronised way which makes it hard to track which images in the visualisation correspond to each other. I would like to make it so visdom only updates every n iterations but its not clear to me how to do this.

Of course, I could make the network return all of its latent variables and call `vis.image` only in the training script, but is there a way to circumvent this?